# run c sharp program without installing in client machine

Tags: c#

I want to run an application in client machine without installing it in the client machine. the application file should be in my usb pen drive and when I go to customer pen is plug in client machine and run the application. The system is developed by c#. Please send any ideas.

Comment: Double click the exe?

Comment: If the .NET framework is not installed on the client machine you will not be able to run any .NET application on that machine before installing the framework.

Comment: Put the .NET installation files on your pen drive.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Is it the runtime he doesn't want installed? In the sentence "I want to run an application in client machine without installing it in the client machine", "*it*" refers to the application, not the runtime... unless the OP phrased it poorly.

Comment: @dcastro: I just wanted to point out that double clicking an exe on an USB key will not work if the framework is not installed on the computer. Perhaps the problem is unsolvable, but the question lack details so it is hard to tell.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Indeed

Comment: customer/client is agreed to install .net framework in client machine. but I cannot run my setup files to install my developed system in client machine.I should run the exe file by duoble clicking it without running setup file

Answer (score 1):

Build it in .Net framework 2. Then you can run it in almost all the windows machine except windows 8. .Net framework 2 is disabled by default in windows 8. You can enable it and run your app. Framework 2 will be available when installing windows and can run by double clicking the exe

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interested in running the `C#` program, there are various online C# compiler available. For eg:

http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php

http://ideone.com/

If it is an application in .exe, you should be able to run it in windows without installing anything, as Windows already contains a version of .Net by default.

If you just have the dlls, scripts etc, you are in deep trouble.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you're after a linker/merger/virtualizer.  I don't have any experience with these tools but they are cited quite often:

- [Xenocode](http://www.xenocode.com/)
- [Thinstall](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/)
- [ILmerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx)
- [Salamander](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/)
- [SkaterPro](http://www.skaterpro.net/linking-net-dlls.html)
- [Spoon Studio](https://spoon.net/studio)